# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/autofill/AutofillManager$AutofillCallback

Tags: java, android, android-autofill-manager

I’m getting the same error on a lot of my tests:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
Landroid/view/autofill/AutofillManager$AutofillCallback;
```

Basically my code introduces `android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.AutofillCallback`, but AutofillCallback is only available on API 26 and up.

I’m guessing this is the cause of the error. Is there a way to get around this for the tests? Put in another way, is there a way to only conditionally import the `AutofillManager` and `AutofillCallback` for specific Build versions?

Here is how I'm introducing the `AutofillManager` and `AutofillCallback`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ... other code not shown

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        final AutofillManager autofillManager = getContext().getSystemService(AutofillManager.class);
        if (autofillManager != null && autofillManager.isAutofillSupported())
        {
            autofillManager.registerCallback(new AutofillManager.AutofillCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAutofillEvent(@NonNull View view, int event)
                {
                    super.onAutofillEvent(view, event);
                    // other code not shown
                }
            });
        }
    }
```